# Android auto reduce data table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am new to Android, and I have a table I made using:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/question_list"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="5dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">
</TableLayout>
```

added rows to it and it perfectly shows the table. Now I want to implement a search box that reduce the result as I type, I am not sure how to do that. I tried searching, maybe I am missing the term to search. Can someone please add a link to it and/or tell me some technique, because re-populating the table everything someone types is like a bad thing to do.

PS: Data is sent from API as JSON, and I own the API.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying large information in TableLayout is bad practice. You can use ListView. Because, every time when text changed in your search box, you need to clear all views in TableLayout, then you need to create rows that appropriate your search filter and then you need to add these rows to TableLayout again. Creating many views and drawing them on screen is hard process for Android and it can crash your app.